# Invoke GetDeviceCaps via DllCall in AutoIt always return same value

Tags: autoit

```
Local $hDC = DllCall("user32.dll", "long", "GetDC", "long", $hWnd)
Local $aRet = DllCall("gdi32.dll", "long", "GetDeviceCaps", "long", $hDC[0], "long", 88)
MsgBox(0, "Result", $aRet[0])
Local $aRet = DllCall("gdi32.dll", "long", "GetDeviceCaps", "long", $hDC[0], "long", 90)
MsgBox(0, "Result", $aRet[0])
DllCall("user32.dll", "long", "ReleaseDC", "long", $hWnd, "long", $hDC)
```

I wrote some codes like above, for some reason, I'd like to get display scaling setting. But I always get the same value "96" no matter what display setting I configured.

Use the same function call in C, I can get the correct value like 96, 144... etc.
Does anyone know how making GetDeviceCaps function work in the AutoIt script?
Thanks!

Below is C code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    int g_DPIScaleX = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);// / 96.0f;
    int g_DPIScaleY = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);// / 96.0f;
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    printf("%d %d\n", g_DPIScaleX, g_DPIScaleY);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Possibly something to do with the way AutoIt is compiled not working with high DPI screens and scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not exactly what you're looking for but i allways check the DPI scaleing over the registry:

```
RegRead("HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop", "LogPixels")
```

EDIT: You can also chage the key with `RegWrite` and Relog/Reboot after to activate it.